# Get a string from a file

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.7

I have a file of titles and passwords formatted like this:

```
<title> <password>
...
```

I need to search the file and return a password given the title in python 2.7. What is the best way to do this? I'm new to working with files so if there is a better way to format the file for this task feel free to make that an answer instead.

Comment: Does this file need to remain human readable or is it just for saving the data? How big can this file be in size?

Comment: the <> is not part of the file, it does not need to be read by a human, and it can be any size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def find_pass(fname,target_title):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for ln in f:
            # some test to see if this is the line you want
            if ln.startswith(target_title):
                return ln[len(target_title):].strip()
```

Comment: What if a line is `"My Amazing Title aPassword"`?

Comment: fair point, edit addresses _that_ pathology, but not a zillion others

Comment: Yea it is probably just safer to suggest `if line.startswith(target)` because of the lack of specs from the OP. Again, what if the line was `"My Amazing<space><space><space>Title aPassword"`?

Answer (score 2):

If your file can be very large and you want to save on loading it all into ram, you can loop over each line, checking for the title value you need. The performance of this approach will depend entirely on how quickly the scan comes across the matching line.

If your file is a reasonable size and can be read into memory, you might consider using [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle) or [`json`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to store your file, and serialize it as a `dict`. That way you can read in the file and instantly pull out the title as a key.

The python [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) module also gives you a higher level object that will act like a dictionary, and handle the serialization to an underlying database file for you. It is basically a persistant dictionary. This will probably be the best balance of efficiency and performance.

Both using a normal dict or using shelve mean no string parsing, as the key is your title and the value is your password.